# Erro em Lua com LOVE2D

Tags: lua, love2d

Estou com um problema em um código em Lua com LOVE2D.
Estou tentando recriar o "jogo da cobrinha" e estou com um problema na função de setupScreen no love.load
O código está assim:

```
WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720

VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 432
VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 243

function love.load()
push:setupScreen(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT {
    fullscreen = false,
    resizable = true,
    vsync = true
})
```

Já usei o mesmo código antes e nunca tive problemas, mas agora quando executo com o love aparece:
main.lua.29: attempt to call global 'WINDOW_HEIGHT' (a number value)

No editor, por algum motivo, o 'WINDOW_HEIGHT' fica da mesma cor de 'setupscreen' da mesma linha (linha 7 nesta pergunta).
Por favor, se alguem puder ajudar ficaria muito agradecido!

Comment: Esse código não compila. Falta `end`. Com isso consertado, dá esse erro: `attempt to index global 'push'`.

Answer (score -2):

Olá, boa noite. O erro aqui é bem simples e comum. Está apenas faltando uma simples virgula após o WINDOW_HEIGHT. Segue o código

```
function love.load()
    push:setupScreen(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT,{
    fullscreen = false,
    resizable = true,
    vsync = true
})
end
```

Muito simples, né? Espero ter ajudado.

Edit: Cometi um pequeno erro no código, mas ja corrigir. Desculpe a inconveniência!

**Bons Códigos :)**

**ASS.:** ***MarcosDev***